# PHP Sessions - Default Save location for Windows

Tags: php, session

What is the default save directory for PHP sessions on a windows machine?

Currently my session.save_path is not set and shows "no value" in phpinfo.

[image]

Comment: Call `session_save_path()` without a value, that will return the current path

Comment: @jszobody shows exactly nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=26757

In summary:  If in your `php.ini` you have `session.save_path = ""` then PHP (on Windows) will use the users `%TEMP%` path.

Remember that this is also dependant on how you run PHP... if it's a "service" (automatically run and/or part of a solution like XAMP) then "user" will be the SYSTEM account --- thus the path will be `C:\Windows\Temp` (or whatever the SYSTEM profile has it's `%TEMP%` *environment variable* set as.)